# ssh bind address through multiple hosts

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, localhost

I'm trying to ssh through multiple hosts which works with no problems like so:

`ssh -t -t user1@host1 ssh -t -t -p 222 user2@host2`

Now I would like to use local host for access to a third host and I do it like so:

`ssh -L 2222:host3:22 -t -t user1@host1 ssh -p 222 user2@host2`

Problem:

When I do `ssh -p 2222 user3@localhost` nothing happens (like that the connection is timing out). Whilst `ssh -t -t user1@host1 ssh -t -t -p 222 user2@host2 ssh user3@host3` works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-L 2222:host3:22` is forwarding a local port 2222 to `host3:22` via `host1`. I assume the `host1` does not have a connectivity to `host3`. If it had, you would not be connecting via `host2`.

You need to forward a port from `host1` to `host2` and then forward the local port to the forwarded port on `host1`.

This should do (I cannot test atm):

```
ssh -L 2222:host2:2223 -t -t user1@host1 ssh -L 2223:host3:22 -p 222 user2@host2
```

> localhost:2222 => host2:2223 => host3:22

Comment: Your assumptions are right. Can you please add the complete command and I will select yours as the best answer. Thank you

Comment: See my edited answer.